# Is intuitivity a word and how do I use it?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

The word *intuitivity* doesn't come up in some dictionaries such as Longman and Oxford, however in some dictionaries (i.e. via Google), the word appears as a correct word even though the actual definition is for intuitive (i.e. see ["intuitively"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/intuitively)). Is it correct to use it in the following sentence?

> Due to the simplicity and intuitivity of Road Map, everyone seems to love it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In essence what you are trying to say with this:

> "Due to [**the simplicity**] and [**intuitivity of**] Road Map, everyone seems to love it."

is this:

> "Due to [**the quality or condition of being plain or natural**] and [**the quality or condition of being easy to use and understand**] Road Map, everyone seems to love it."

The word ***simplicity*** is a noun, but there is no equivalent word that is derived from ***intuition*** (intuitivity) to go with it in that context. The only matching derivative of *intuition* that will be found in a dictionary, is also a noun, and is widely accepted and understood is ***intuitiveness***.

Your options are to either use the accepted word (intuitiveness) or use *intuitivity*, but place quote marks around it:

> "***Due to the simplicity and "intuitivity" of Road Map, everyone seems to love it.***"

Answer (score 11):

"Intuitiveness" is much more common than "intuitivity".  The spell-checker (which is quite good) recognizes "intuit", "intuition", "intuitive", and "intuitiveness", but does not recognize "intuitivity".

I can intuit meanings of "intuitivity", but one of my guesses is not what you mean.  If intuitivity is analogous to creativity, then intuitivity might mean "a person's ability to design intuitive things".  I assume you mean "the intuitiveness of a thing."

Comment: "Due to the simplicity and intuitiveness of Road Map, everyone seems to love it," is a perfectly fine sentence.

Answer (score 3):

"Intuitivity", while having an intuitive meaning (pun intended), is a seldom-used word. As other commenters have pointed out, your best bet might be to rephrase your original sentence.

> Everyone seems to love Road Map because it's simple and intuitive.

or

> Due to it being simple and intuitive, everyone seems to love Road Map.

or

> Due to its simplicity and intuitive use, everyone seems to love Road Map.

or

> Due to the simplicity and intuitive interface/use/nature of Road Map, everyone seems to love it.

Comment: this might be an alternative to avoid using "Intuitivity" by paraphrasing the sentence, however this is not an answer to my question. Thank you though.

Comment: You are welcome! The answer to your question is that it depends on who your audience is. Apparently, "intuitivity" is sometimes used in technical circles to mean "ease of use", as in here: (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_utility_%28system_engineering%29). It can also mean "possessing a strong sense of intuition", although that's limited to discussions of philosophy. In summary, the word has very specialized use, and if your audience is not specialized, it would be "wrong" from a pragmatic standpoint.